# Hi, I have container, contain numbers of box images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have container, contain numbers of box images. when i mouseover the image hide box will appear on the image. but when i use this script all the box get open...

```
$(".conbx img").mouseover(function() {
    $(".topics-active").show()
});

$(".conbx img").mouseout(function() {
    $(".topics-active").hide()
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/xqfv3fhq](http://jsfiddle.net/xqfv3fhq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to get the current elements `siblings`.

```
$(".conbx img").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".topics-active").show()
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xqfv3fhq/1/

**Optimizations**

```
$(".conbx").on('mouseover', 'img', function() {
    $(this).siblings(".topics-active").show()
}).on('mouseout', 'img', function() {
    $(".topics-active").hide()
});
```

Alternatively, you can also use `hover`:

```
$(".conbx img").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".topics-active").show()
}, function() {
    $(".topics-active").hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(".conbx img").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).next('.topics-active').show()
});

$(".conbx img").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).next('.topics-active').hide()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$(".conbx img").mouseover(function(){
     $(this).closest('.fltlft').find(".topics-active").show();
});
$(".conbx img").mouseout(function(){
     $(this).closest('.fltlft').find(".topics-active").hide();
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqfv3fhq/3/)

or you can just use just css without need to jquery at all

```
.fltlft:hover .topics-active{
    display: block;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xqfv3fhq/4/)